# element.scrollLeft could not be set to an accurate value

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQFIP.png)
As showed in the picture, when I set the scrollLeft to 3815, next time I read the value, it becomes 3814.22216796875. Not sure it happens in the browser write or read process

How to set or read the accurate value?

Comment: It might help us if you could include a little runnable snippet which shows the problem - currently I can't reproduce it but that may be because I've missed some setting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example